# highlighting a line in jtextpane; Java

Tags: java

how i can do it? in code
forexample:
JTextPane tp;
...
tp.hightlight(num);// num is number of line

Comment: example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTextPaneHighlightExample.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great example for you: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/line-painter/